# ExoPlayer HlsMediaSource() deprecated

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

The `HlsMediaSource()` method is deprecated (I'm currently on `exoplayer:2.6.1`). What is the recommended method to use for HLS-media instead?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

After digging into the source code I concluded that

```
HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataFactory).createMediaSource(mediaUri)
```

is the way to go.

**Edit:** Expanding on the other factories

The factory pattern is also the recommended way to instantiate  `ExtractorMediaSource`, `SsMediaSource`, `DashMediaSource`, and `SingleSampleMediaSource` as per the [2.6.1 release notes](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/RELEASENOTES.md).

The factory methods simplifies `MediaSource` instantiation, especially in cases when you wish to configure optional parameters whilst leaving others set to their default values, e.g.

```
DashMediaSource.Factory(chunkSourceFactory, manifestDataSourceFactory)
    .setManifestParser(new CustomManifestParser())
    .createMediaSource(manifestUri, eventHandler, eventListener)
```

Comment: Thanks! +1 : I assume similar solutions apply for depreciated functions `SsMediaSource`, `DashMediaSource`, and  `ExtractorMediaSource`.

Comment: Thats correct :) Maybe I should add that to the answer as a side note.

Comment: @Abhishek `val dataFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, "ua")`

Comment: I was able to figure that out already. But really thanks for answering

Comment: I'm glad to hear!! Sorry for the delay :)

Answer (score 4):

If you cannot find HlsMediaSource you will need to add one more dependency:

```
implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:$exoplayer_version"
```

To implement it we need to have code similar to this:

```
val userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(context, USER_AGENT)

DefaultDataSourceFactory(
                context,
                userAgent
            )

val source = "https://some_url_link"
val uri = source.toUri()

HlsMediaSource.Factory(factory).createMediaSource(uri)
```

Comment: Fixed my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way to get rid of deprecated

```
 val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, "sample")
    ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse(uri)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use newest version: `com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.2`

This code will work for you:

```kotlin
val defaultHttpDataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(URL)
val mediaSource = HlsMediaSource.Factory(defaultHttpDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(mediaItem)
exoPlayer?.apply {
setMediaSource(mediaSource)
seekTo(playbackPosition)
playWhenReady = playWhenReady
prepare() 
}
```